# Should I use a static or instance class in this specific case?

Tags: c#, scope, state, static-classes

I have read the posts regarding when to use static classes and when it is recommended to use instance classes. However, I have the impression my example below somewhat falls in between:

- No class instances are needed, stored state is shared among members within the AppDomain.
- State should be accessible from different class instances within the AppDomain.
- No abstractions or overrides are ever needed.

So, my question is: Should I go ahead and use it as static or is it better to use a singleton concept?

```
public static class SubscriptionManager
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> Repository { get; set; }

    static SubscriptionManager()
    {
        Repository = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public static void Subscribe(string key, string value)
    {
        if (Repository.ContainsKey(key))
            Repository[key] = value;
        else
            Repository.Add(key, value);
    }

    public static void Unsubscribe(string key, string value)
    {
        if (Repository.ContainsKey(key))
            Repository.Remove(key);
    }

    public static string GetSubscription(string key)
    {
        if (Repository.ContainsKey(key))
            return Repository[key];
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need any of your `ContainsKey()` checks.  For `GetSubscription()`, use `TryGetValue()`; elsewhere, always call `Remove()` or the setter.

Comment: if Repository dictionary is some data that you want to use every where, in my opinion it is OK.

Comment: @user2675751, yes the functionality that the static members provide, which in turn rely on the state stored, must be accessible by several **different** class instances within the same AppDomain. I basically feel I am left with two choices, pass instances around and a static class.

Comment: @SLaks, fair points, thanks. But what do you think should it be static or instance? I am somewhat not convinced that "if it holds state it MUST be instance" must be universally applied.

Answer (score 0):

Remember large static classes can take up a lot of memory so avoid them when not necessary.
in this case i would suggest you to go with static classes. It is better this way.

Comment: Thanks but a) I do not see the rational why static classes take up any more memory (even those holding states) than the sum of parts, so to speak (referring to several class instances that store state that in sum amounts to the same amount of data stored than state stored in a static class), b) I would like to hear the rational why here a static class is preferable or not.

Comment: @MattWolf: Values of static fields will never be GC'd (unless you clear the fields).  Whether this is an issue or not depends entirely on your design.

Comment: @SLaks , sure but given the intent is to share state and make state accessible to different class instances and sub-classes within the appDomain they would not be GCd as well, no? The purpose of the state specifically here in this example is to share state throughout the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your example provides an explicit implementation of a Repository-like pattern which in the end may prove more valuable if it was extensible. If you implement this as a static class you're making the decision now that this should not be possible.

An example of another possibly valuable implementation might be to use the .NET 4 `ConcurrencyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` so the code can be used in higher volume, concurrent scenarios since the `Dictionary` class isn't thread safe.

What you're suggesting is very YAGNI, which is good for iterations of large project with some sort of plan in place, but unless you know what the future holds why limit the potential of code already written?

I'd probably generate an interface from your class to represent its bare bones (to separate the implementation from the contract), and utilize an IoC container to make the user of your class decide what implementation to use for their scenario.

Of course this only matters if your project is fairly small or otherwise care about sharing code between projects. Good luck!

Comment: this is a solution exclusively for this project, only. And the purpose is well defined with no extensibility planned. I currently use an instance class and it is highly inefficient because I need to pass the instance to each and every single accessor, no matter how deep in sub classes. (btw, the code is just a sample to describe the issue, it does not reflect the actual state or functionality)